# Is there a template engine for Visual studio (MVC 5 framework)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i am currently working on a project using VS 2013 MVC 5, i have been asked to use a template, i am trying to find out, is there a template tool/engine for visual studio mvc? something similar to Thymeleaf for eclipse mvc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is a default template in VS when creating an MVC Application, which is basically a working application with basic features and login. Bare in mind, this is a simple "Hello World!" project, but it's a good place to start your application.

I recommend this tutorial:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

/ChrisRun

Answer (score 1):

The [Razor](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29) view engine is built in to ASP.NET MVC 5. You are also able to plugin alternatives should you wish.

Comment: my company is buying custom template from Themeforest, i want to be able to integrate it into my mvc project.